# Get key for a map<string,vector<string>>

Tags: c++

how can i get keys for such a map `map<string,vector<string>>mymap` assuming that `mymap["index"]={"val1","val2"}`? I have found the solution here for a normal map like `map<string,string>` but for this i don't know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "get keys"? And how is this different from a "normal map"?

Comment: map["index"].vector_method ....? aka map["index"].at(0) will access the first string? / map["index"].push_back("hello");

Comment: Yes, and i want to get the 'index'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate through all the values in the map (which are pairs) and refer their first and second element to obtain, respectively, the key and the mapped value:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> m;
    // ...
    for (auto& p : m)
    {
        std::string const& key = p.first;
        // ...

        std::vector<std::string>& value = p.second;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course, you could achieve the same using `std::for_each` instead:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> m;
    // ...
    std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), [] (
        std::pair<std::string const, std::vector<std::string>>& p
        //                    ^^^^^
        //                    Mind this: the key is constant. Omitting this would
        //                    cause the creation of a temporary for each pair
        )
    {
        std::string const& key = p.first;
        // ...

        std::vector<std::string>& value = p.second;
        // ...
    });
}
```

Finally, you may also roll your own manual `for` loop, although I personally consider this less idiomatic:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> m;
    // ...
    for (auto i = begin(m); i != end(m); ++i)
    {
        std::string const& key = i->first;
        // ...

        std::vector<std::string>& value = i->second;
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

This is how the last example above would look like in C++03, where type deduction through `auto` is not supported:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_map;
    my_map m;

    // ...
    for (my_map::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::string const& key = i->first;
        // ...

        std::vector<std::string>& value = i->second;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: auto i = begin(m); instead of this i can use a 'map<string,vector<string>>::iterator i'?

Comment: @siloan: You can, but why would you bother writing all that stuff?

Comment: Hmm at the moment of iteration for some reasons i get a don't send error after last index.

Comment: windows error - 'program.exe has stopped working' after printing the last index.

Comment: @siloan: If I can't see your code it's hard for me to debug it. Maybe you can ask a new question where you paste the whole code you are trying and ask why you get an error. The way I showed for iterating is correct.

Comment: @siloan: Also, which one of the proposed solutions are you using?

Comment: Ups my mistake i had something wrong in my code, sorry for that and thanks again for your solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The map holds `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>` internally, so iterating over the map gives you access to the keys via `it->first`, where `it` is the iterator.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> m;

for (auto it = m.cbegin(), it != m.cend(); ++it)
  std::cout << "key " << it->first << std::endl;
```

The range based loop version is

```
for (const auto& stuff : m)
  std::cout << "key " << stuff.first << std::endl;
```